# Why are 'hidden' directories in OCaml projects prefixed with an underscore?

Tags: ocaml, project

Examples are _opam and _build, these are commonly seen in OCaml projects and it baffles me that they don't use the usual dot prefix.
Is there a historical significance to this unique choice?

Comment: I don't consider them hidden. They are just special in that they only contain generated files. Using _ as prefix is probably just a way to avoid name collisions with stuff normaly present in sources and a prefix that no OS has a problem with. Might also be influenced by _ denoting the reserved namespace in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably for the same reason `.vimrc` files are called `_vimrc` on Windows:

> vimrc files in windows generally start with an underscore, "_vimrc" as Windows Explorer won't let you create files starting with a dot. Similarly, the ".vim" directory is called "vimfiles" on windows.

(from https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3v7g86/cant_get_vimrc_working_on_windows/cxkz9nr/ )